# Writing SQL query equivalent to relational division of relational algebra?

Tags: relational-division

> ```
> EMPLOYEE (Ssn#, Fname, Lname, Bdate, Address, Sex, Salary, Super_ssn)
> WORKS_ON (Essn#, Pno, Hours)
> PROJECT (Pnumber#, Pname, Plocation)
> ```
>
> Question 1: Write an SQL query (equivalent to relational division of relational algebra) to retrieve the project name which is contributed by all employees.
>
> Question 2: Write an SQL query (equivalent to relational division of relational algebra) to retrieve the first name and last name of all employees who work on every project.
>
> ```
> ITEM (Item#, Item_Name, Unit_Price)
> ORDER (Order#, Ord_Date, Cust#, Ord_Amt)
> ORDER_ITEM (Order#, Item#, Qty)
> WAREHOUSE (Warehouse#, Warehouse_City)
> SHIPMENT (Order#, Warehouse#, Ship_Date)
> WAREHOUSE_ITEM (Item#, Warehouse#, Qty)
> ```
>
> Question 3: Write an SQL query (equivalent to relational division of relational algebra) to list Item_Name and Quantity that are stored in all warehouses in Sydney.

My answer for Question 1:

```
SELECT Pname 
FROM PROJECT
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT Pname 
    FROM PROJECT, EMPLOYEE 
    WHERE PROJECT.Pnumber = WORKS_ON.Pno);
```

My answer for Question 2:

```
SELECT Fname, Lname 
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT Fname, Lname 
    FROM EMPLOYEE, WORKS_ON, PROJECT
    WHERE EMPLOYEE.Ssn = WORKS_ON.Essn 
    AND WORKS_ON.Pno = PROJECT.Pnumber);
```

My answer for Question 3:

```
SELECT Item_Name, Qty 
FROM ITEM, ORDER_ITEM
WHERE ITEM.Item# = ORDER_ITEM.Item#
AND EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM WAREHOUSE 
    WHERE Warehouse_City = 'Sydney');
```

(If these are correct, I will able to convert them in relational algebra with relational division.)

What are the mistakes in my SQL queries?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short and concise article describing the various techniques for relational division in SQL, with an example similar to yours using students and courses instead of employees and projects:
http://www.inf.usi.ch/faculty/soule/teaching/2016-fall/db/division.pdf

It offers three equivalent solutions:

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT x.Student
> FROM taken AS x
> WHERE NOT EXISTS (
> SELECT *
> FROM required AS y
> WHERE NOT EXISTS (
> SELECT *
> FROM taken AS z
> WHERE (z.Student=x.Student)
> AND (z.Course=y.Course)));
>
> SELECT Student FROM Taken
> EXCEPT
> SELECT Student FROM (
> SELECT Student,Course
> FROM (select Student FROM Taken), Required
> EXCEPT
> SELECT Student,Course FROM Taken);
>
> SELECT Student
> From Taken
> WHERE Course IN (SELECT Course FROM Required)
> GROUP BY Student
> HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Required);
> ```

Answer (score -1):

The third seems correct.  The first and second strike me as wrong.  You are looking for projects where any employee contributed, not where all contributed.  In essence you are doing a division on an ANY rather than an ALL criteria.

In these cases you need to change your queries to use `NOT EXISTS` and look for mismatches.

Comment: All 3 seem wrong. Question 3 has "all", too.